# SwiperJS - How to show four fixed-width slides for desktop and center active slide for mobile and tablet

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, swiper.js

I have a carousel where the requirements state to show four slides for desktop. The slides have a fixed width for all viewports and are 280 pixels wide with 32px spaceBetween. The issues I'm trying to resolve are these on mobile and tablet:

1. Center active slide.
2. Clicking pagination bullet advances slides properly and centers the new active slide.

Here's what I have, which is also in Codepen (https://codepen.io/Codewalker/pen/jOXzYXa?editors=1111):

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-cards-container">
  <div class="title-container">
    <h2>Show four slides on desktop and center active slide for tablet and mobile</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper carousel-cards">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>Business Fiber</h3>
          <p>Provides the speed, security, and reliability you need to collaborate effectively across various business locations</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>Business Unlimited Wireless Plans</h3>
          <p>Unlimited talk, text, and data with no overage charges</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>Phone for Business</h3>
          <p>Crystal-clear sound quality and more than 30 calling features over an Internet for Business connection</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>Dedicated Internet</h3>
          <p>Offers the fastest speeds, nationwide availability, and 100% uptime guaranteed - or we'll credit your account</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>Wireless Broadband</h3>
          <p>A flexible, wireless alternative to traditional broadband</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>Switched Ethernet</h3>
          <p>Adaptable, on-demand, and secure private service that connects two or more business locations</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="/content/dam/attbusiness/images/cards/card-image-01.png" alt="">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>Office@Hand</h3>
          <p>Integrated phone, video, and messaging designed to work seamlessly across your business devices</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="slide-text">
          <h3>SD-WAN</h3>
          <p>Intelligent dynamic routing, optimized cloud connectivity, and visibility into applications and performance</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-cards {
     margin: 0 auto;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .carousel-cards-container {
     height: 555px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-height: 1355px;
     max-width: 1440px;
     background-image: url("/content/dam/attbusiness/images/cards/bluevector.png"), linear-gradient(#FFF 10%, #009FDB 10%, #009FDB 60%, #009FDB 60%);
     background-position: center top 135px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
}
 .carousel-cards-container .title-container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     height: 140px;
     padding: 10px;
}
 .carousel-cards-container .title-container h2 {
     font-family: attAleckSans-Bold, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 32px;
     text-align: center;
}
 .swiper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     max-height: 332px;
     position: relative;
}
 .swiper-slide {
     font-size: 18px;
     background: #fff;
     border: 1px solid gray;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
     border-top-left-radius: 25px;
     border-top-right-radius: 25px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: flex-start;
     align-items: center;
     width: 280px;
     max-width: 280px;
     min-width: 280px;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .swiper-slide img {
     width: 280px;
}
 .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     border-radius: 60px;
     z-index: 9999;
}
 .swiper-button-prev {
     left: 50px!important;
}
 .swiper-button-next {
     right: 50px!important;
}
 .swiper-pagination {
     height: 48px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     position: relative;
     padding-top: 30px;
     width: 128px!important;
}
span.swiper-pagination-bullet.swiper-pagination-bullet-active-main {
     transform: none;
     -webkit-transform: none;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet {
     background-color: #fff !important;
     height: 8px!important;
     width: 8px!important;
    margin: 0 4px;
     opacity: unset;
     transform: none;
     -webkit-transform: none;
}
 .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
     outline: 1px solid white;
     outline-offset: 3px;
}
 .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {
     background-color: transparent;
     background-size: 100%;
     width: 40px!important;
     height: 40px!important;
     position: absolute;
     top: 60%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     border: none;
     border-radius: 60px;
     z-index: 9999;
}
 .swiper-button-prev {
     left: 0;
     background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 1.25C9.64466 1.25 1.25 9.64466 1.25 20C1.25 30.3553 9.64466 38.75 20 38.75C30.3553 38.75 38.75 30.3553 38.75 20C38.75 9.64466 30.3553 1.25 20 1.25ZM20 36.25C11.0254 36.25 3.75 28.9746 3.75 20C3.75 11.0254 11.0254 3.75 20 3.75C28.9746 3.75 36.25 11.0254 36.25 20C36.25 24.3098 34.538 28.443 31.4905 31.4905C28.443 34.538 24.3098 36.25 20 36.25ZM17.8625 11.6125L26.25 20L17.875 28.3875L16.1 26.6125L22.7125 20L16.0875 13.3875L17.8625 11.6125Z" fill="white"/></svg>');
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
 .swiper-button-next {
     right: 0;
     background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M20 1.25C9.64466 1.25 1.25 9.64466 1.25 20C1.25 30.3553 9.64466 38.75 20 38.75C30.3553 38.75 38.75 30.3553 38.75 20C38.75 9.64466 30.3553 1.25 20 1.25ZM20 36.25C11.0254 36.25 3.75 28.9746 3.75 20C3.75 11.0254 11.0254 3.75 20 3.75C28.9746 3.75 36.25 11.0254 36.25 20C36.25 24.3098 34.538 28.443 31.4905 31.4905C28.443 34.538 24.3098 36.25 20 36.25ZM17.8625 11.6125L26.25 20L17.875 28.3875L16.1 26.6125L22.7125 20L16.0875 13.3875L17.8625 11.6125Z" fill="white"/></svg>');
}
 .swiper-slide h3 {
     font-family: attAleckSans-Bold, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 20px;
     margin-top: 0;
}
 .swiper-slide p {
     font-size: 15px;
}
 .slide-text {
     padding: 10px;
}
 .swiper-wrapper {
     max-width: 1280px;
}
 @media (min-width: 576px) {
     .carousel-cards-container {
         background-image: url("/content/dam/attbusiness/images/cards/bluevector.png"), linear-gradient(#FFF 20%, #009FDB 20%, #009FDB 60%, #009FDB 60%);
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 768px) {
     .carousel-cards-container {
         background-image: url("/content/dam/attbusiness/images/cards/bluevector.png"), linear-gradient(#FFF 60%, #009FDB 30%, #009FDB 30%, #009FDB 30%);
         background-position: center;
    }
     .carousel-cards-container .title-container h2 {
         font-size: 38px;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 992px) {
     .carousel-cards {
         width: 80%;
    }
    .carousel-cards-container {
         height: 555px;
    }
     .swiper-slide {
         font-size: 18px;
         width: 280px;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .carousel-cards {
         width: 80%;
    }
     .carousel-cards-container {
         background-image: url("/content/dam/attbusiness/images/cards/bluevector.png"), linear-gradient(#FFF 40%, #009FDB 30%, #009FDB 30%, #009FDB 30%);
         background-position: 0 200px;
    }
}
 @media (min-width: 1400px) {
    .carousel-cards {
         max-width: 1216px;
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

JS

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".carousel-cards", {

    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
        onlyInViewport: false,
    },
    loop: true,
    mousewheel: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    slidesPerView: 4,
    spaceBetween: 32,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        dynamicBullets: true,
        dynamicMainBullets: 2,
        clickable: true
    },
    updateOnWindowResize: true

});
```

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints

Comment: 'breakpoints' doesn't work for 'centeredSlides'